# How to track the 3d movement of a small animal in a 4x4x8 meter cage?

Tags: sensor, rfid, gyro, movement, 3d

I need to track the movement of a small animal (60 grams) in a cage which contains plants, shelter, branches and so on. I need all three coordinates in real time.

Spatial resolution should should not exceed 10 cm. 
Temporal resolution shouldn't be less than 3Hz.
Recording time would be as long as possible but not shorter than 3 hours.
Ideal solution would be unintrusive to the animal.

So far I have considered these options and their drawbacks:

1. Cameras: There would be at least three cameras and the position would be obtained by image analysis of the resulting frames. This would be very difficult if the animal is out of sight (in shelter or behind leaves).
2. IMU: I have no experience with IMU and the animal cannot carry more than a few grams.
3. GPS-like methods: The animal would carry a small passive RFID chip, there would be several sensors outside, and the position would be computed based on trilateration. However I have no experience here either and I do not know if this is possible for such a small space.

I have an unlimited budget even for high end devices.

Comment: The pros are using video tracking for this sort of thing. http://www.plexon.com/products/cineplex-tracking-option

Comment: If you have an unlimited budget I wonder why you ask here instead of hiring some professional

Comment: A few more parameters please? How long must the system operate without attention? (For example how long must a power supply last if a device is attached to the small animal). When you say "real time", how frequent must the measurements be? Within that sample rate, how precise and accurate must measurements be, i.e. within 1mm, 1cm, 10cm, etc?

Comment: I do not hire a professional because this is side project of mine. Even though my lab has unlimited resources I don't have an power to hire anyone. Its just a small but inevitable part.

On the other hand I have no idea who to hire in such a case, that's why I seek for suggestions here.

Comment: Infrared cameras and software?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I am allowed to post URLS to products, but search for decaWave -- they have 3D low power trackers with 10 cm resolution.

If there are (optical) obstructions, then cameras won't work; you'll need an RF technique.

Comment: "I don't know if I am allowed to post URLS to products"  Yes you can.  But you need to provide enough description to search with in case the link breaks, as you did.  So best to do both.